# I need to write Webdriver code to upload a track in my application using python

Tags: python, automation, upload, webdriver

I am trying to upload file using `send_keys()` but I noticed that in my application It doesn't have input type element so I just tried with other tags and getting error "element not interactable".

Please suggest if there is any other method to implement uploads.

Thanks